# How can I make the vimdiff command use the same Vim version as the vi and vim commands?

Tags: debian, vim, version, alternatives, vimdiff

I've never worried about `vimdiff` on my own computer, where I have archlinux installed, so everything is up-to-date, generally speaking; I generally just used it, and I'm fine with it. After all, `:version` gives the same output whether I launch `vi`, or `vim`, or `vimdiff`.

On my work computer (Debian 10), however, `vimdiff` opens an older version of Vim than `vi` or `vim`.

I guess this has to do possibly with how I installed Vim and/or with `/etc/alternatives` or something. It's been a long time I played around with such stuff though (without truly understanding it, likely), so I don't remember much.

---

**Feedback on [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/695929/164309)** and comment(s)

```bsh
ls -lF /etc/alternatives/ | grep bin/vim | sed 's/.*-> //' | sort -u
```

rsults in just in one result, namely `/usr/bin/vim.gtk*`. How is it possible, then, that `vimdiff` and `vim` open different versions? Or have I misunderstood the answer?

The output of `type -a vimdiff` is

```
vimdiff is /usr/bin/vimdiff
vimdiff is /bin/vimdiff
```

output of: `type -a vim`

```
vim is aliased to `/home/me/vim-dist/bin/vim'
vim is /usr/bin/vim
vim is /bin/vim
```

output of `type -a vi`:

```
vi is aliased to `/home/me/vim-dist/bin/vim'
vi is /usr/bin/vi
vi is /bin/vi
```

Both `/bin/vim --version | head -n 1` and `/usr/bin/vim --version | head -n 1` have the same output:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 15 2019 16:41:15)
```

and that's the version that runs when I execute `vimdiff`, older than the one that runs when I execute `vim`/`vi`.

Comment: Add the output of `type -a vimdiff`, and follow where that path leads

Comment: @muru, added to the question.

Comment: Debian's `vim` packages don't install install into /bin, they install into /usr/bin.  Have you installed a non-packaged version of vim / vimdiff into /bin?   Did you delete the /etc/alternatives/vimdiff symlink?   Please add the output of `/bin/vim --version | head -n 1` and `/usr/bin/vim --version | head -n 1` to your question.

Comment: Yes, I have installed a non packaged version of Vim. I downloaded the repo and installed from it, but I didn't worry about vimdiff, thinking it would be isntalled together with vim. Apparently that's not the case?

Comment: OK.  Is /usr/bin/vimdiff a symlink to /bin/vimdiff?   are there any other vim binaries in /bin, or is it just vimdiff?  is /bin/vimdiff a standalone binary or a hard- or symbolic link to another binary (maybe vim)?

Comment: You gave the output of `type -a vimdiff`, but what's the output of `type -a vim`/`type -a vi`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason WHY you installed a non-packaged version of vim?  It can't be "newer version" - Debian already has vim 8.2. And why into /bin rather than /usr/local/bin?    /bin and /usr/bin belong to system (i.e. debian-packaged) binaries.  /usr/local/bin (and /opt) belong to sysadmin-compiled stuff and third-party software.  You can ignore that if you like, but you'll risk breaking your system as you have done here, or even worse if you do it with more "essential" software.

Comment: @cas, `/usr/bin/vimdiff` -> `/etc/alternatives/vimdiff` -> `/usr/bin/vim.gtk`; `/bin/vimdiff` -> `/etc/alternatives/vimdiff` -> `/usr/bin/vim.gtk`; at the time I installed it, Debian had no 8.2, but just 8.1, which I believe is the version that `vimdiff` is using. And I needed 8.2. As regards why in `/bin`, I don't remember, maybe I just made the wrong thing.

Comment: well, now that debian has 8.2, I very strongly recommend that you uninstall your unpackaged version (and try to avoid impatience in future - it's very rarely worth the bother, even for major versions....and I doubt very much that a .1 version bump would have been worth the hassle it caused).  and then fix the /etc/alternatives symlinks.  probably the easiest way to do that is to remove or purge the debian vim packages and re-install them.   BTW, the vim-gtk package is obsolete....it's now a dummy transitional package that depends on vim-gtk3.  BTW, see https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian

Comment: I couldn't use YouCompleteMe, which amounts to "I couldn't code", basically. Anyway, would purging and re-installing the debian versions fix all the mess?

Comment: almost certainly.  uninstall the vim you installed to /bin/ first.

Comment: BTW, YouCompleteMe is in debian package `vim-youcompleteme` and Depends on `python3:any, python3-future, python3-requests (>= 2.2.1), python3-requests-futures, ycmd-core-version (= 44), vim-nox | vim-python3`, and Recommending `vim-addon-manager`.      `vim-python3` is a virtual package provided by `vim-nox`, `vim-gtk3`, and `vim-athena`.    Except in extremely rare circumstances, it is almost always better to install a packaged version of software than non-packaged - even if it happens to have a lower version number.   There are quite a few plugin pkgs: try running `apt-cache search -n vim`

Comment: If before doing anything else I run `sudo apt install vim` (just to see what it would install; then I remember I can press `n` to not proceed, so I can first uninstall stuff), debian tells me `vim is already the newest version (2:8.1.0875-5)`.

Comment: Besides, I'm sure I've installed Vim 8.2 myself as a non-packaged version, I still have the directory where I built it in my home; but I don't think I have installed Vim 8.1 that way. I think it was the packaged version at that time.

Comment: Furthermore, @cas, if I do `sudo apt update` nothing gets updated, but 29 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.` If  I run that, `vim` is not listed there. So I guess my Debian 10 still has only Vim 8.1? (By the way, this Debian is the machine I use in my work office, not mine.)

Answer (score 1):

You've aliased `vi` and `vim` to the one in `/home/me/vim-dist/bin`; presumably you'd also be fine just aliasing `vimdiff` as well.

For `vimdiff` to work properly it needs to be executed as "vimdiff" not as "vim" so you can't just alias "vimdiff" to `/home/me/vim-dist/bin/vim` as well.

However, there might already be a symbolic link in `/home/me/vim-dist/bin` named `vimdiff`. If there is then alias "vimdiff" to that.

If not it would probably work to create it.

```
cd /home/me/vim-dist/bin
ln -s vim vimdiff
```

Then alias "vimdiff" to `/home/me/vim-dist/bin/vimdiff`.

If you don't want to or can't create the links, it would probably work to alias "vimdiff" to `/home/me/vim-dist/bin/vim -d`.

```
alias vimdiff="/home/me/vim-dist/bin/vim -d"
```

(In your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or wherever you keep your aliases.)

An alternative to all the aliases would be to add `/home/me/vim-dist/bin` to your `$PATH` and make sure it appears *prior* to  `/bin` and `/usr/bin`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16560332/what-is-this-path-in-linux-and-how-to-modify-it) if you're not familiar with changing your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Huh?  `vimdiff` is just a symlink to `vim`.   On debian specifically, `/usr/bin/vimdiff` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/vimdiff` which is, in turn, a symlink to your preferred version of vim.

e.g. on my main desktop machine, with `vim.gtk3` as my preferred vim:

```
$ ls -lF /usr/bin/vimdiff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 May 18  2018 /usr/bin/vimdiff -> /etc/alternatives/vimdiff*

$ ls -lF /etc/alternatives/vimdiff
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Nov  8  2019 /etc/alternatives/vimdiff -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
```

You can see the available alternatives with:

```
$ update-alternatives --list vimdiff
/usr/bin/vim.basic
/usr/bin/vim.gtk3
```

and change it with:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config vimdiff
There are 2 choices for the alternative vimdiff (providing /usr/bin/vimdiff).

  Selection    Path                Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/vim.gtk3    50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/vim.basic   30        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/vim.gtk3    50        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

If I had more vim packages installed (like `vim-tiny`), then they would appear as options too.

It's possible to have different alternatives selected for vim and vimdiff (and several other `*vim*` programs - see below for some of the binaries).  I suspect that's what you've done.  If you want them to be the same, then use `update-alternatives` to change one or both of them.

```
$ ls -lF /etc/alternatives/ | grep bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 editor -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 eview -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 evim -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 gview -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Dec 24  2019 gvim -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 gvimdiff -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 rgview -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 rgvim -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 rview -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 rvim -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 vi -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 view -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Nov  8  2019 vim -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  17 Mar 18 21:58 vimdiff -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk3*
```

(alternatively, you could run something like `grep -r bin/vim /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/`)

Each of those can independently be set to point to a different alternative version of vim.   I probably should install `vim-tiny` (or at least set most of the above to `vim.basic`), I don't really need fancy GUI or perl/python/ruby/tcl support built in to my vi.  The only time I even use `gvim` is on the rare occasions when I run it from a GUI app or a file-browser.

Comment: Hi cas, I've update the question with some feedback. Would you mind giving a look at it?